# Deleting files of mounted drive using MFC c++

Tags: c++, winapi

[I want to delete first 10 files of the mounted drive. This drive is Unix system drive. I have written code which working fine for local drive but not mounted drive. Its deleting randomly but not sequentially.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESRsM.png) I have written code in MFC C++. Please Let me know if any one knows the solution. The code is like below.

```
char fileFound[256];
WIN32_FIND_DATA info;
HANDLE hp=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
int count=10;
swprintf_s(fileFound,256,"%s\\*.*","G:\\foldername");
hp=FindFirstFile(fileFound,&info);
do
{
    swprintf_s(fileFound,256,"%s\\%s","G:\foldername",info.cFileName);
    DeleteFile(fileFound);
    count--;
}while(FindNextFile(hp,&info)&&count);
FindClose(hp);
```

Comment: `swprintf_s(fileFound,256,"%s\\%s","G:\foldername",info.cFileName);`  Have you debugged it? You are using a single ` \ ` character instead of two like you do before the loop.

Comment: I have tried with double `\' also. Its not working.

Comment: Check if `DeleteFile` returns `FALSE`, if yes then check [GetLastError()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) which will tell you why the file could not be deleted.

Comment: The order of appearance of files with FindFirstFile/FindNextFile is unspecified. See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29734737/findnextfile-order-ntfs)

Answer (score 0):

> Its deleting randomly but not sequentially.

This behavior is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418.aspx):

> [...] `FindFirstFile` does no sorting of the search results.

As well as [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428.aspx):

> The order in which the search returns the files, such as alphabetical order, is not guaranteed, and is dependent on the file system. If the data must be sorted, the application must do the ordering after obtaining all the results.

If you need to delete the first *n* files from a set of files, you need to gather the entire set of files, sort the set based on an arbitrary predicate, and then perform an action on the first *n* items.

Comment: But in local system drive its sorting of the search result automatically. Not in mounted drive.

Comment: @MaheshTimmanagoudra: This has nothing to do with local drive vs. mounted drive. The order in which results are returned is *"dependent on the file system"* (as explained in the answer). NTFS may return sorted (by some predicate) results, whereas ext3 may not. Even if you are dealing with a sorted result set, the order may not be what you need, because there are several ways to sort a set (e.g. dictionary or phone book order). Or maybe NTFS simply sorts the results by ascending UTF-16 code unit values.